# php - remove extra whitespace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I got the following string, the result from decoding hex to string,

```
" g e t  s m h "
```

but the result should be,

```
"get smh"
```

I believe it can be done using preg_replace, but I have no idea with regex. Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\s(?!\s)
```

And replace with nothing.

`\s(?!\s)` will match every whitespace character (and newlines and carriage returns and formfeeds and tabs but if it's a single line, this shouldn't be a problem) unless they are followed by another space character, so that in "  " (2 spaces), only the second space is replaced by nothing.

You use it like this:

```
$newstring = preg_replace('/\s(?!\s)/', '', $oldstring);
```

Comment: I tried preg_replace('\s(?!\s)', '', $string) and I got the following error, Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: You need to use delimiters. I thought you knew how to use them? I'll add the usage in my answer in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try This. hop it will work

```
$str = " g e t  s m h ";
$str = explode('  ', $str);
$str_1 = str_replace(' ', '', $str[0]);
$str_2 = str_replace(' ', '', $str[1]);
echo $str_1.' '.$str_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone find this to convert hexadecimal to string without extra whitespaces and preg_replace, I'm finally get it work using mb_convert_encoding

```
mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $hexstring), 'ASCII', 'UCS-2');
```